# What are the exact requirements for The Floor is Lava?

Tags: achievements, overwatch

One of the two achievements in Overwatch that are specific to Lucio is called "The Floor is Lava", which requires you to get three killing blows whilst wall riding. Does that mean you simply need to be wall riding at the moment of the kill, or when firing the killing projectile? Maybe even both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Video might help you.

You must be riding a wall while killing three enemies without dying in between the kills. To clarify, you need to be wall riding when the elimination happens and you receive the notification on your screen. What the guy does, and seams to be easier is to push them off the map and just ride till they hit the bottom.

Comment: Worth noting, the important part about the knockback strategy is you need to get credit for the killing blow, and you need to be actively wall-riding when the elimination message appears on screen.

Comment: Lucio starts at 4:58. He gets the achievement at 13:20. Takeaways: you don't have to wallride for the whole time, just at the moment each enemy is eliminated. You can blast someone off an edge while on the ground, then jump up on a wall til they actually die, then go back to the ground until the next one.

Comment: If you could esplicitly mention that you only need to be wall riding when the elimination happens, I'll accept it.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer there 'ya go.